# AdbClient error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

I am getting this error when I issue a device.takeSnapshot() command and device.touch() command:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\AndroidViewClient_Bots\pytesser\insta_get_list_of
_users.py", line 82, in <module>
    device.touch(213,481, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-7.0.2-py2.7.egg\com\dtmi
lano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 425, in touch
    self.shell('input tap %d %d' % (x, y))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-7.0.2-py2.7.egg\com\dtmi
lano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 257, in shell
    self.__send('shell:%s' % cmd, checkok=True, reconnect=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-7.0.2-py2.7.egg\com\dtmi
lano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 154, in __send
    self.__checkOk()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-7.0.2-py2.7.egg\com\dtmi
lano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 184, in __checkOk
    recv = self.socket.recv(4)
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the softwar
e in your host machine
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PIL import Image # Python Image Library

try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient, Device
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, View


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(verbose=True)


my_img = device.takeSnapshot()
device.touch(200,300, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

It is really strange because if I ONLY have

```
my_img = device.takeSnapshot()
```

or

```
device.touch(200,300, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

then I get no error. But together, in the same code, it generates the above error. Is there something I am not doing when issuing multiple device commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky I guess.
Your problem may come from the fact that `device.takeSnapshot()` is defined as

```
def takeSnapshot(self, reconnect=False):
    '''
    Takes a snapshot of the device and return it as a PIL Image.
    '''

    ...
```

so, if you are planning to keep using the connection after taking the snapshot use

```
device.takeSnapshot(reconnect=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This also worked: `AdbClient(serialno=serialno).takeSnapshot()`